# unable use compare to with two different generic object with different T types

Tags: c#, generics, comparison

I have two types that both extend a generic base type. Both types have no additional properties and only assign values to the abstract values. When I try to compare the two types, using `CompareTo` I get an exception stack trace a mile long that stems from a failed type case.

Is it possible to compare the two types if I'm trying to cast with generics?

Here is the code:

Starting type:

```
public interface IIdentifier : IEquatable<IIdentifier>, IComparable<IIdentifier>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Numerical identifier
    /// </summary>
    long Id { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provide the type of identifier.
    /// </summary>
    IdentifierType IdType { get; }
}
```

The Base Identifier type that the next two types extend:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseIdentifier<T> : IIdentifier, IComparable<BaseIdentifier<T>>, IComparable, IEquatable<BaseIdentifier<T>> where T : class, IIdentifier
{
    #region Properties

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public abstract IdentifierType IdType { get; }

    #endregion
    #region Constructors

    protected BaseIdentifier(long id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    protected BaseIdentifier()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEquatable<IIdentifier> Members

    public bool Equals(IIdentifier other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        return this.IdType == other.IdType && this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparable<IIdentifier> Members

    public int CompareTo(IIdentifier other)
    {
        int c = this.IdType.CompareTo(other.IdType);
        if (c != 0)
            c = this.Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
        return c;
    }

    #endregion
    #region IComparable<BaseIdentifier<T>> Members

    public int CompareTo(BaseIdentifier<T> other)
    {
        return Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparable

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return CompareTo(obj as BaseIdentifier<T>);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEquatable<BaseIdentifier<T>> Members

    public bool Equals(BaseIdentifier<T> other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        return this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Here are the two types that throw an exxeption when trying the `CompareTo` using the `BaseIdentifier<T>` function.

```
[DataContract]
public class Type1 : BaseIdentifier<Type1>
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override IdentifierType IdType
    {
        get { return IdentifierType.Type1; }
    }

    public Type1(long Id)
        : base(Id)
    {
    }

    public Type1()
    {
        // For serialization
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Type2 : BaseIdentifier<Type2>
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override IdentifierType IdType
    {
        get { return IdentifierType.Type2; }
    }

    public Type1(long Id)
        : base(Id)
    {
    }

    public Type2()
    {
        // For serialization
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'Domain.Contracts.Type2' 
to type 'Domain.Contracts.Type1`1[Domain.Contracts.Type1]'.""   
at Domain.Contracts.BaseIdentifier`1.CompareTo(Object obj) in 
C:\\xsr\\path\\BaseIdentifier.cs:line 109\r\n   
at Xceed.Utils.Data.ObjectDataStore.CompareData(Object xData, Object yData)\r\n   
at Xceed.Utils.Data.ObjectDataStore.Compare(Int32 xRecordIndex, Int32 yRecordIndex)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewSort.Compare(Int32 xDataIndex, Int32 yDataIndex)\r\n   
at Xceed.Utils.Collections.IndexWeakHeapSort.Sort(Int32 length)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewGroupRoot.SortRootRawItems(SortDescriptionInfo[] sortDescriptionInfos, List`1 globalRawItems)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionView.SortItems(SortDescriptionInfo[] sortDescriptionInfos)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionView.ExecuteSourceItemOperation(DeferredOperation deferredOperation, Boolean& refreshForced)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DeferredOperationManager.Process(Boolean processAll)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewBase.DeferRefreshHelper.ProcessDispose(DataGridCollectionViewBase collectionView)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewBase.DeferRefreshHelper.Dispose(Boolean disposing)\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridCollectionViewBase.DeferRefreshHelper.System.IDisposable.Dispose()\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridSortDescriptionCollection.DeferResortDisposable.Dispose()\r\n   
at Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.ColumnSortCommand.Disposer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)"
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ exception?  If the stack trace is "a mile long" it sounds like you may have an infinite recursion.  Can you run it in the debugger and break in the `CompareTo` method?

Comment: It's a mile long because it's trying to get a property off a null type, inside of a compare on a third party grid system. So the third party grid system is what causes the exception to be so long. See the update for the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CompareTo(ojbect)` code is trying to cast a `BaseIdentifier<Type1>` to a `BaseIdentifier<Type1>` which is not legal.

Since you can't compare objects with different generic parameters, it seems like you should change

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    return CompareTo(obj as BaseIdentifier<T>);
}
```

to

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    return CompareTo(obj as IIdentifier);
}
```

so that you bind to the overload that takes the *interface* rather then the generic type.

You might also consider overloading `Equals(object)`, redirecting it to `Equals(IIdentifier)`, which means you *also* need to overload `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Yep, I've tied this, and it does work. I just didn't know if there was something else I was doing wrong that could be corrected for the parameter version to work.

Comment: I've edited the question to (hopefully) explain _why_ it doesn't work.  I don;t see anything else obvious that you're missing.  you just need to make sure you bind the overloads to the right base methods.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how generics work in C#. The generic syntax is really just to make your life easier, but you have to remember that changing out the generic type really makes it a *different type*. So `BaseIdentifier<Type1>` is a completely different type from `BaseIdentifier<Type2>`. You write it once in your code, but at compile time they're separated.

Figuring out how to implement exactly what you're going for can be complicated. The easiest option based on your example above is to make it implement `IComparible<IIdentifier>` rather than using the generic type.

Comment: Are you saying just implement `IComparible` and not `IComparible<T>`?